# SQLite and PHP listing categories

Tags: php, sqlite

I want to list each category and the each faq q&a underneath for each category. Right now the code below just list all the q&a by category but not the category name. Is there an easy fix for this? I am a total newbie and would really appreciate some help!

```
<? $result = sqlite_query($db, "SELECT * FROM faqs ORDER BY faqcategory DESC");
                            while($row = sqlite_fetch_array($result)) {?>
                            <div class="midBoxContent">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><?php echo $row['faqquestion'];?></li>
                                </ul>
                                <p><?php echo $row['faqanswer']; ?></p>
```

Comment: What does your result table look like?

Answer (score 0):

```
<? $faqc = "";
$result = sqlite_query($db, "SELECT * FROM faqs ORDER BY faqcategory DESC");
   while($row = sqlite_fetch_array($result)) {?>
<?php
// check if the category is changing...
if ($faqc != $row['faqcategory']){
  // it's changed, write it out..
 echo  $row['faqcategory'];
 $faqc = $row['faqcategory'];
}
?>
   <div class="midBoxContent">
     <ul>
      <li><?php echo $row['faqquestion'];?></li>
     </ul>
      <p><?php echo $row['faqanswer']; ?></p>
```